# How to align a text layout to the left and an image to the right in android

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm trying to align my arrow to the very right of the screen but for some reason the arrow places itself to much to the left for my liking. I have looked at plenty of other examples but for some reason they aren't working.

[image]

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/list_item3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="42dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/list_item"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="#DCDBDB" >

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="33dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/quotedevil" />

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="21sp" 
    android:text="@string/quoteDevil"/>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="51dp"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:src="@drawable/nextarrow" />

            <!-- Put line under text -->


            </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `layout_alignParentRight` doesn't work in a `LinearLayout` it's a `RelativeLayout` parameter. So you could switch to a `RelativeLayout` but the easier solution is to make your `TextView` fill the available space:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="21sp" 
    android:text="@string/quoteDevil"/>
```

PS: Not directly related but Android Studio warns you about stuff like this (only mention it because of the Eclipse tag in the OP :))

[image: Android Studio Rocks!]

Answer (score 0):

Also the android:layout_centerHorizontal and android:layout_centerInParent doesnt work for LinearLayout. Try with this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/list_item3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="42dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/list_item"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="#DCDBDB" >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="33dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                android:src="@drawable/quotedevil" />

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="21sp" 
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:text="@string/quoteDevil"/>

          <ImageView
            android:layout_width="51dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:src="@drawable/nextarrow" />
```